# Elasticsearch: count number of hits in each document

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like to know how many times a search term appears in a given field of each document. For example, given the following document

```
{
  "id": 123,
  "my_sentence": "There are many trees in the park. The trees are large and small"
}
```

and the search term of `trees`, what kind of query would produce a result like

```
{
  "id": 123,
  "hits": 2
}
```

I have seen answers that are old and use a `script`, such as

```
"script_fields": {
   "tf": {
       "script": "_index['field_to_search']['search_term'].tf()"
   }
 }
```

However, this only seems to work when the search term is a single word, and the particular field being searched is not stemmed.

Comment: Why for security reasons?

Comment: I was mistaken. There used to be a security hole with scripts but it has been fixed. I'll update the question.

Comment: What ES version?

Comment: Currently running 2.3.5, but could upgrade